# Data Selected from a table variable is not in the same order that it was inserted?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table variable with the datatype Varchar(MAX).

I am inserting the value 'header' first, Then based on an inner join, I am next inserting 'Details' into the same table variable. Finally, I am inserting 'Trailer'.

The output which I am getting is in the order: 'header', then 'trailer', and finally 'details'.

My required output is in this order:

```
Header 
Detail
Trailer
```

But I am getting this order:

```
Header
Trailer
Detail
```

Note: I am not able to use asc/desc in the selection. I am inserting in the order I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A SQL Database does not actually understand what order you put things in, or store the data in a given order. You probably want a second column in your table with a value to use so that whatever order you need is preserved.

Think about it like handing some stuff to your friend to hold - she will have all of it for you later, but she stores it someplace in the mean time. She may move it around while you are not looking to make room for something else, or may hand it back in the same order you gave it to her, but you didn't tell her to keep it in order, so she doesn't.

Databases need to be able to move things around in the background, so the way they are built does not intrinsically know about any order - you need to know the order when you give it to the database, so that you can put it back in the order you want later. The order clause allows SQL to impose an order on the data, but it doesn't remember or have one on its own.

Comment: You could also put these different things (Header,Trailer,Detail) in separate columns, which might make more sense. It seems that the data stored in header, detail, etc. shouldn't necessarily be the same - so why not hold onto it in a way that makes more sense. This of course depends on a liot of things we do not know.

Comment: Another way to think about your analogy - hand your friend a stack of $1 bills, which she subsequently drops on the floor. Now ask her to pick them back up and give them back to you in the same order you gave them to her. She might be able to do that if your original order was by serial number, and she has some time to kill...

Answer (score 6):

If you don't include an ORDER BY in the outer query, don't expect SQL Server to read your mind. There is no guarantee that SQL Server will return data in the order it was inserted. You should add a column to your table variable called `[rank]` or something. When you insert the header, insert 1, for the details rows, insert 2, then for the trailer insert 3. Now you can add `ORDER BY [rank];` to the end of your query, have predictable results, and everyone is happy.

Comment: But the insert order will be there in the output. Isnt it?

Comment: No, you are thinking inserting into a table is like inserting into a flat file; it's not. If you don't provide an order by, SQL Server is going to return the rows in whatever order it deems most efficient. *Sometimes* that will match the order of insert, but not always.

Comment: @jesvin - Only if you add an `ORDER BY` clause on your statement, there is no *insert order* if you don't add one column that store it

Comment: Just to be clear, even if you do `INSERT ... ORDER BY` it doesn't mean that same `ORDER BY` will be respected when you `SELECT`. In other words, @Lamak meant for you to add an `ORDER BY` to your `SELECT` statement, not the `INSERT`.

Comment: You might try adding an ID column to your table variable - then the optimizer might return the records in ID order: ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL.

Comment: @RussellFox not guaranteed. Just as one counter-example, put a primary key on another column. Unless the alphabetical or numerical order on *that* column happens to match the insert order, the most likely outcome (but still not guaranteed) is going to be `boom`.